# In a custom Grails env, how do you get code changes to auto-update without a restart

Tags: grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, grails-2.0

I have a custom Grails Environment:

[image]

I must use this custom env instead of the dev env for several reasons during development.

Is there something I can set in Config.groovy for my custom env that will allow saved code changes from my IDE, GGTS(Groovy&Grails Tool Suite), to automatically be pushed to the app which is running locally like it happens in dev.

Currently, after I do a custom run-app and make any changes to the source, those changes are not reflected in my locally running app.  I have to restart the server to see the changes.

How do you get an custom Grails environment to perform like the dev environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `--reloading` flag, e.g.

```
grails -Dgrails.env=custom --reloading run-app
```